# looping array inside foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```html
$count =  "SELECT *
FROM corseprv
WHERE std_class = '$c_name' ORDER BY std_class ASC ";
$countres = mysqli_query($link,$count);
foreach ($countres as $row);
```

```
$img_arr = array('kid1.png','kid2.png','kid3.png','kid4.png','kidz1.png','kidz2.png','kidz3.png','kidz4.png');
```

and this foreach loop

```
?>
<html >
<div style="text-align: center" >
    <h1>שיבוץ כתתי  - <?= $c_name?> </h1>
</div>


<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <?php $a; foreach ($countres as $row) : ?>
        <img src="img/cut.png" style="width: 150px">
        <li style="font-size: 20px"><?=$a.') '.''.$row['std_class'].' : '.$row['std_name'].' - '.$row['select1'].' ,'.$row['zavta1']  ?> <img  style="width: 20px;" src="img/<?= $img_arr[$a]?>"></li>

        <?php $a++; endforeach; ?>
    <img src="img/cut.png" style="width: 150px">
</ul>
</html>
```

my problem is that the array is not running all the way of the foreach loop and stopping after the array ends. how can I make it run according to the for each loop

Comment: What's `$countres`?

Comment: up dated the post

Comment: Ignoring the sql injection risk in your query, does it return enough results to match the length of `$img_arr`?

Comment: A foreach stops when the array ends. That is what they are meant to do. What are you expecting?

Comment: That's how a foreach works. Ends when the array ends.

Comment: You are not running that loop based on your image array variable. If your `$countres` variable has less data then the `$img_array`, it's totally expected that the loop ends before the reaching the other array's end.

Comment: let me rephrase my question : i have the pic array that i want to run according to the foreach result and not the way around , my foreach loop it not stopping the array is stopping,

Comment: `<?php $a;` should that be `<?php $a=0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just do everything inside the `<?php ?>`

```
$a = 1; // or else = 0

foreach ($countres as $row) {
    echo '<img src="img/cut.png" style="width: 150px">';
    echo '<li style="font-size: 20px">'
    echo $a.') '.''.$row['std_class'].' : '.$row['std_name'].' - '.$row['select1'].' ,'.$row['zavta1'];
    echo '<img  style="width: 20px;" src="img/'.$img_arr[$a].'"></li>'
    $a++;
}
```

Or else you just forgotten to add value to your `$a`

Comment: ?? `$a = 0;` ?? or you will never see `kid1.png`